# Selecting from selection with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, select-by-expression

The expression box has a handy "select from selection" button. Is there a way to emulate this with Python? I have the basic expressions down, but can't find a way to do this.

Comment: Something unexpected came up so I had to deal with that first.. but I tested your solution just now. Works great!

Comment: You could try to use your ids with request.setSubsetOfAttributes .

Comment: For anyone testing this on QGIS < 2.99, they should use `ids = vl.selectedFeaturesIds()` instead :)

Comment: @Matte do you suggest to use `request.setSubsetOfAttributes` with the first request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find the option from the API, but you could mimic such behavior this way:

I assume there are selected features already, so get their Ids:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
selIds = lyr.selectedFeaturesIds()
```

You said you have an expression, let's say:

```
expr = QgsExpression( "\"NMG\" = 'CALI'" )
```

Now, get feature Ids that match your expression:

```
it = lyr.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
newIds = [i.id() for i in it]
```

Get only those that are already selected and match your expression (this is the magic part):

```
idsToSel = list( set(selIds).intersection(newIds) )
```

Finally, select them:

```
lyr.setSelectedFeatures( idsToSel )
```

Comment: setSelectedFeatures should work up to QGIS2.16 but will be/has been deprecated in newer versions. See [here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a4d82285142c108ba73622ce53207759c). New coders should try this instead:

    lyr.selectByIds( idsToSel )

Comment: That's right, thanks! There are upcoming API changes that will make tons of GIS.SE answers obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

To select from the selected objects (filter the current selection) in QGIS 3, I used [IntersectSelection](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a7bc5759667b4447129eb3d8966551909), it Modify current selection to include only select features which match.

```
layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
myExpression = '\"population\" > 100'
layer.selectByExpression(myExpression, QgsVectorLayer.IntersectSelection)
```

From the current selection, only objects with a population greater than 100 will remain selected. If there was no current selection, then no objects will be selected.