# Select by expression only for selected features using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, features, getfeature, select-by-expression

I'm facing a *nested* problem using PyQGIS (for QGIS master, but it can be replicated in any version of QGIS 2).

I have a vector layer with some selected features and with a `QgsFeatureRequest` I can easily loop only on the selected features:

```py
vl = iface.activeLayer()
# get the list of selected ids 
ids = vl.selectedFeatureIds()

# create the request with the selected ids
request = QgsFeatureRequest()
request.setFilterFids(ids)

# use only the selected features in getFeatures
for i in vl.getFeatures(request):
    print(i.attributes())
```

Then I build an expression based on a field of the attribute table and I can use `QgsFeatureRequest()` to filter only the features that match that expression:

```py
exp = ''' "Piper" = 1 '''
request = QgsFeatureRequest()
request.setFilterExpression(exp)

for i in vl.getFeatures(request):
    print(i.attributes())
```

but what if I want to filter with the same expression only the already selected features?

So actually use both requests in the same `getFeatures` loop?

Comment: I agree it could be a handy option in the QGIS API, but you can also use the answer to [How to select from selection with PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137146)