# PyQGIS layer action: Select features within buffer having the same field value

Tags: pyqgis, expression, actions, typeerror, qgsfeaturerequest

By means of a [PyQGIS layer action](https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/qgis-actions.html#introduction), I am looking for a way to select all polygon features within a buffer polygon sharing a certain field value (e. g. provinces belonging to the same country) with the feature I have clicked on.
I got stuck in the part of the code combining the getFeatures method with a selecting expression, which throws the following TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 26, in 
TypeError: QgsFeatureRequest(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: too many arguments
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  overload 4: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  overload 5: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  overload 6: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

The full code is:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
        
layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'
feature_id = [%$id%]
feature_name = '[%name%]'
field_name = 'iso_a2'
field_value = '[%iso_a2%]'
expression = f'"{field_name}" = \'{field_value}\''
   
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(layer_id)

buffer_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:3857&field=fid:integer", f'{feature_name}_buffer_500km', "memory")
buffer_layer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857))

buffer_distance = 500000
for feature in layer.getFeatures([feature_id]):
    geom = feature.geometry()
    buffer = geom.buffer(buffer_distance, 5)

f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(buffer)
buffer_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([f])
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffer_layer)
iface.setActiveLayer(layer)

layer2 = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expression)) # This line throws the TypeError
intersecting_features = [
                    p.id() 
                    for p in layer.getFeatures(buffer.boundingBox())
                    if p.geometry().intersects(buffer)
                    ]
if intersecting_features:
    layer2.selectByIds(intersecting_features)
```

Data for this working example comes from the [natural earth data set](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/), layer: ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces (used crs: 3857)

How has the code to be changed in order to get the intended result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396755/183146), I finally found a solution:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
        
layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'
feature_id = [%$id%]
feature_name = '[%name%]'
field_name = 'iso_a2'
field_value = '[%iso_a2%]'
expression = f'"{field_name}" = \'{field_value}\''
   
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(layer_id)

buffer_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:3857&field=fid:integer", f'{feature_name}_buffer_500km', "memory")
buffer_layer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857))

buffer_distance = 500000
for feature in layer.getFeatures([feature_id]):
    geom = feature.geometry()
    buffer = geom.buffer(buffer_distance, 5)

f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(buffer)
buffer_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([f])
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffer_layer)
iface.setActiveLayer(layer)

intersecting_countries_ids = [
    c.id()
    for c in layer.getFeatures(buffer.boundingBox())
    if (c.geometry().intersects(buffer)
    )
    ]
if intersecting_countries_ids:
    layer.selectByIds(intersecting_countries_ids)
layer.selectByExpression(expression, QgsVectorLayer.IntersectSelection)
```